# how to restore Desktop files from iCloud

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop

Basically I signed out and in my apple Id to fix some handoff issues....
But I just noticed that all my files on Desktop DISAPPEAR !!!

I have the desktop folder in my iCloud but not sure what happens..
I restarted the laptop but won't fix..

Trash bin doesn't have the files from desktop either...

2018 Macbook Pro, OS: latest Big Sur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to store your Desktop and Documents folders in iCloud, make sure the feature is selected in System Preferences > Apple ID > iCloud Drive (Options) > Desktop and Documents Folders.

If this option is selected and you still don’t see your Desktop and Documents folders in the desktop of your Mac but still see these similarly titled folders inside of your iCloud folder, then what you can do is drag and drop the files you would like to have on your desktop and the same for the Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences... -> iCloud -> Options -> iCloud Drive -> Select the checkbox for Desktop & Document Folders.